# PySpark in Eclipse: using PyDev

Tags: eclipse, python-2.7, apache-spark, pydev, pyspark

I am running a local pyspark code from command line and it works:

```
/Users/edamame/local-lib/apache-spark/spark-1.5.1/bin/pyspark --jars myJar.jar --driver-class-path myJar.jar --executor-memory 2G --driver-memory 4G --executor-cores 3 /myPath/myProject.py
```

Is it possible to run this code from Eclipse using PyDev? What are the arguments required in the Run Configuration? I tried and got the following errors:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/myPath/myProject.py", line 587, in <module>
    main()
  File "/myPath/myProject.py", line 506, in main
    conf = SparkConf()
  File "/Users/edamame/local-lib/apache-spark/spark-1.5.1/python/pyspark/conf.py", line 104, in __init__
    SparkContext._ensure_initialized()
  File "/Users/edamame/local-lib/apache-spark/spark-1.5.1/python/pyspark/context.py", line 234, in _ensure_initialized
    SparkContext._gateway = gateway or launch_gateway()
  File "/Users/edamame/local-lib/apache-spark/spark-1.5.1/python/pyspark/java_gateway.py", line 76, in launch_gateway
    proc = Popen(command, stdin=PIPE, preexec_fn=preexec_func, env=env)
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/subprocess.py", line 711, in __init__
    errread, errwrite)
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/subprocess.py", line 1308, in _execute_child
    raise child_exception
OSError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory
```

Does any one have any idea? Thank you very much!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Considering the following prerequisites:

- Eclipse, PyDev and Spark installed.
- PyDev with a Python interpreter configured.
- PyDev with the Spark Python sources configured.

Here is what you'll need to do:

- From Eclipse ID, Check that you are on the PyDev perspective:

  - On Mac : Eclipse > Preferences
  - On Linux : Window > Preferences
- From the *Preferences* window, go to PyDev > Interpreters > Python Interpreter:

  - Click on the central button [Environment]
  - Click on the button [New...] add a new Environment variable.
  - Add the environment variable SPARK_HOME and validate:
  - Name: SPARK_HOME, Value: /path/to/apache-spark/spark-1.5.1/
  - **Note :** Don’t use the system environment variables such as $SPARK_HOME

I also recommend you to handle your own `log4j.properties` file in each of your project.

To do so, you'll need to add the environment variable `SPARK_CONF_DIR` as done previously, example:

```
Name: SPARK_CONF_DIR, Value: ${project_loc}/conf
```

If you experience some problems with the variable ${project_loc} (e.g: with Linux), specify an absolute path instead.

Or if you want to keep `${project_loc}`, right-click on every Python source and: Runs As > Run Configuration, then create your `SPARK_CONF_DIR` variable in the Environment tab as described previously.

Occasionally, you can add other environment variables such as `TERM`, `SPARK_LOCAL_IP` and so on:

- Name: TERM, Value on Mac: xterm-256color, Value on Linux: xterm , if you wan to use xterm of course
- Name: SPARK_LOCAL_IP, Value: 127.0.0.1 (it’s recommended to specify your real local IP address)

**PS:** I don't remember the sources of this tutorial, so excuse me for not citing the author. I didn't come up with this by myself.

Comment: I found a full guide here: https://enahwe.wordpress.com/2015/11/25/how-to-configure-eclipse-for-developing-with-python-and-spark-on-hadoop/. The instructions in the post of eliasah didn't worked for me and I think that all was about the Py4J configuration

Comment: Followed all the steps above mentioned but i am still getting the following error--------------------- 
  raise Exception("Java gateway process exited before sending the driver its port number")
Exception: Java gateway process exited before sending the driver its port number