# Spark development process with Python and IDE

Tags: python, apache-spark, pycharm

What is the standard development process involving some kind of IDE for spark with python for

1. Data exploration on the cluster
2. Application development?

I found the following answers, which do not satisfy me:

a) Zeeplin/Jupiter notbooks running "on the cluster"

b)

- Install Spark and PyCharm locally,

  - use some local files containing dummy data to develope locally,
  - change references in the code to some real files on the cluster,
  - execute script using spark-submit in the console on the cluster.
  - source: https://de.hortonworks.com/tutorial/setting-up-a-spark-development-environment-with-python/

I would love to do a) and b) using some locally installed IDE, which communicates with the cluster directly, because I dislike the idea to create local dummy files and to change the code before running it on the cluster. I would also prefer an IDE over a notebook. Is there a standard way to do this or are my answers above already "best practice"?

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to use any IDE with [PySpark](https://towardsdatascience.com/how-to-use-pyspark-on-your-computer-9c7180075617). Here are some instructions for [Eclipse](https://enahwe.wordpress.com/2015/11/25/how-to-configure-eclipse-for-developing-with-python-and-spark-on-hadoop/) and [PyDev](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33326749/pyspark-in-eclipse-using-pydev):

- set HADOOP_HOME variable referencing location of winutils.exe
- set SPARK_HOME variable referencing your local spark folder
- set SPARK_CONF_DIR to the folder where you have actual cluster config copied (spark-defaults and log4j)
- add %SPARK_HOME%/python/lib/pyspark.zip and 
  %SPARK_HOME%/python/lib/py4j-xx.x.zip to a PYTHONPATH of the interpreter

For the testing purposes you can add code like:

```
spark = SparkSession.builder.set_master("my-cluster-master-node:7077")..
```

With the proper configuration file in SPARK_CONF_DIR, it should work with just `SparkSession.builder.getOrCreate()`. Alternatively you could setup your run configurations to use spark-submit directly. Some websites with similar instructions for other IDEs include:

- [PyCharm](https://hortonworks.com/tutorial/setting-up-a-spark-development-environment-with-python/)
- [Spyder](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24249847/running-pyspark-on-and-ide-like-spyder)
- [PyCharm & Spark](https://kaizen.itversity.com/setup-spark-development-environment-pycharm-and-python/)
- [Jupyter Notebook](https://www.datacamp.com/community/tutorials/apache-spark-python)
- [PySpark](https://towardsdatascience.com/how-to-use-pyspark-on-your-computer-9c7180075617)